# Is it a good practice to make the sibling class as parent class as the parent class loses its meaning?

Tags: oop, inheritance, refactoring

I have a parent class, say `Parent`, and two classes extending `Parent`, say they are `Sibling1` and `Sibling2` respectivily. As the development going on and more changes are made, I found that having `Parent` doesn't make a lot of sense since `Sibling1` will be exactly the same as `Parent`.

I feel removing `Parent` and having `Sibling1` as `Sibling2`'s superclass can make the code cleaner, but the problem is, it doesn't make sense to make `Sibling1` as `Sibling2`'s parent since in the code they shouldn't inheritance relationship.

How should I balance the the situation? Suppose I have to make `Sibling1` and `Sibling2` have some correlation since they share a lot of the logic in the existing code.

Comment: You need to share your code which will help others to correlate your question better. Please follow this guideline to update your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move all common logic to `Parent` and keep `Sibling1`, even if it will be a class which adds nothing on top of `Parent`. You should not make `Sibling1` the parent of `Sibling2` if that does not make sense from a domain perspective.

A point you should consider is that having `Sibling1` as the parent of `Sibling2` does not make your code cleaner, it just allows you to achieve the same behavior (for now at least) via *less code*. Less code does not always translate to *better design*.